# jqGrid not available even though imported properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having a problem getting the jqGrid to be recognized by jQuery. For some reason despite having imported the library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I can verify that the library is imported correctly and I can click on it and see it in Chrome. Any idea why I cannot use the library? When I try

```
 JQuery("#table").jqGrid...
```

it doesn't work, nor does it show up as one of the functions available.

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery should be first then jQueryUI then jqGrid, this is because jqgrid depends in jquery an djqueryui so they need to be loaded before.

I think you also need `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` loaded before too

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js">   </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```